# Using f:event to inject a ConversationScoped bean into a ViewScoped bean

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, seam3

I can't inject a ConversationScoped bean into a ViewScoped bean, because the ConversationScoped bean could be shorter lived than the ViewScoped one, or vice versa, depending on whether or not the ConversationScoped bean is long-lived.

To get over this limitation, I tried using an f:event to perform the injection as a preRenderView listener:

```
<f:metadata>
   <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{taskController.initializeTask(workPackageConversation.workPackage)}" />
</f:metadata>
```

This howver is not working, neither the listener initializeTask, nor the getter getWorkPackage are being called.

I realize I can lookup one managed bean from another, using the FacesContext, but I am curious why this isn't working.  Is it because the f:event listener isn't called when I navigate to a view from another view?  ie. without a redirect or direct page view?

I also tried the s:viewAction tag from Seam 3 Faces, to no avail.   It does not get called either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think the lifetime issues would not come into play since you've always got a proxy to the normal-scoped bean anyway.  You either dereference the conversation-scoped bean while the *conversation* is active, or it's not active -- but you'll always get the right conversation.